# If $f'(x)$ has atleast one root in $[a,b]$,then $f(x)$ has atleast two roots in $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus

Is this statement true?
 
If $f'(x)$ has atleast one root in $[a,b]$,then $f(x)$ has atleast two roots in $[a,b]$.If it is true,then how to prove it?

---

I think this statement is true but i do not know how to prove this.I have applied this statement in some problems and i am getting correct answer.But i want to learn its proof.

Comment: What if $f(x) = x$?

Comment: Or what about $x^2+2$ in any interval including 0.

Comment: Counter-example: $f'(x)=x$, it is $0$ between, say $[-2,2]$, but it's antiderivative, which we could choose to be $f(x)=x^2 +100$ obviously doesn't have any roots.

Comment: Actually, as from the comment above, you should add to your statement "upon a suitable choice of the antiderivative constant". In fact, if $f'(x)$ crosses $0$ you have a local max or min, and you can find some constant $c$ such that $f(x)+c$ crosses $0$ two times.

Comment: and note that $f'(x)$ has one root in $[a,b]$ is not the same as $f'(x)$ has one root in $]a,b[$ (which is what you are thinking to)

Comment: You may say that if $f'(x)$ has 2 roots in $[a,b]$ and these 2 roots represent  a max. and a min. points, then there is a root for $f(x)$ in [a,b]. I don't know if this is a theorem or not.

Comment: @NoChance  I think that is false, too. For example $\;(x^3-4x+8)'=3x^2-4\;$ vanishes at two points in $\;[-2,2]\;$ which are maximum and minimum of the function, yet the function itself doesn't vanish at all in $\;[-2,2]\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo, you are correct. I was thinking of changing signs in an interval, not min. and max. Thx for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true,
$$
  f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R},x\mapsto x^2 + 1
$$
is a counter example.

But if you need to show that for some $c$, $f+c$ has two roots in $[a,b]$ you could try to prove it using $f$'s Taylor series. Namely let $\xi\in(a,b)$ be the root of $f'$ then
$$
  f'(x-\xi) = 0 + r_1x + o(x)
$$
hence 
$$
  f(x-\xi) = r_0 + \frac{r_1}{2}x^2 +  o(x^2).
$$
Now you see that if $r_1\not=0$ chosing $c= -r_0 \pm \epsilon$ where the sign should be oposite to the one of $r_1$ shows the claim.

Now as pointed out by @zhw if $r_1=0$ we can't tell. In general let $f\in C^{2k}((a,b),\mathbb{R})$  such that for some $\xi\in(a,b)$
$$
 f^{(i)}(\xi) = 0, \forall 0\leq i <2k
$$
and the $2k$-th derivative $f^{(2k)}(\xi)$ doesn't vanish then
$$
 f(x) =r_0 + r_{2k}x^{2k} + o(x^{2k})
$$
 chosing 
$$
  c = -r_0 -\epsilon r_{2k}
$$
for some small $\epsilon >0$ yields the claim.

Comment: "But if you need to show that for some c, f+c
 has two roots ..."   No, $x^3 + c$ has only at most one root in $\mathbb R$ no matter what $c$ is.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly, the problem was that I expected $r_1$ to be non zero which is not the case in your example. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @  zhw : but $x^3$ does not have 3 coincident and real roots ?